# chrome dev tools mobile display vs actual iphone display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

I have a website, http://jackylei.space/pokeapp/, that looks differently on the chrome dev tools version of mobile display vs the actual display of the site on my iphone 6+. Am I doing something wrong? I want to make sure I can test bootstrap properly before launching on my desktop but seems like the chrome dev tools is not accurate.

**chrome dev tools display of iphone 6 site**
[image]

**actual iphone 6+ display**
[image]

Comment: Seems that you are your Mac OS (X). Try with Safari dev tool.

Comment: ok i realized that it has to deal with safari causing this chnage. how would i go about figuring out why the format is different in chrome vs. safari?

Comment: They use different engines. Although one is fork of the other, they behave slightly differently.